# Interpreting Histogram of Run Length

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I have a histogram showing the length of time before an event happens. The length of time varies.

Taking a histogram of the data if I see that there are 10 runs of length 5 but but only 8 runs of length 6. For this data set does this mean that there is an 80% chance that I will see a run of 6 given that I have seen a run of 5.

Does this say anything about whether the run increments are independent or not?

Thanks

Comment: Does the histogram also show other lengths of run ?

Comment: Yes there are runs at 1,2,3,4 as well as 5 and 6

Comment: Are the lengths of time independent of each other ? You have to  post more details what the histogram is  about.

Comment: I am trying to figure out if the lengths of the runs are independent. From the above it seems that there is an 80% chance of seeing a run of 6 if you have already seen a run of 5 (is that part correct)?

Comment: From the histogram only you cannot say if the lengths of the runs are independent. Is there no explanatory text ?

Comment: That's what I thought but can I say that there is an 80% chance of seeing a 5 if you have a 5 even if this probability is independent?